# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)

Tags: objective-c

While using the iphone simulator 64 bit, i'm getting the following architecture error. Also using the  xcode 5.0. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

have a look under your build settings, check that the setting `Build Active Architecture Only` is set to `No` (might make compiling a bit slower but should fix the problem)

Also check that the `Valid Architectures` has arm64 in the list

Note if you are getting an error when submitting an app saying "Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include both armv7 and armv7s architectures”, setting it to No will also fix this

Comment: Thanks man,it did the trick but some third party sdk is throwing some linker errors...eg: ad sdks.

Comment: sounds a bit strange, i dont think it would be related to this though, try do a complete clean (hold option or alt when pressing clean project)

Comment: Phew! The real answer. All the answers recommending `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO` at the same time tell us to increase build times and binary sizes.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is just set the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO`. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]if you getting error on test xcode project then delete it also resolved this problem.

other way is todo

I had the same error message after upgrading to XCode 5.1. Are you using CocoaPods? If so, this should fix the problem:

```
Delete the "Pods" project from the workspace in the left pane of Xcode and close Xcode.
Run "pod install" from the command line to recreate the "Pods" project.
Re-open Xcode and make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No" in the build settings of both the "Pods" project and your own project.
Clean and build.
```