# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, iphone-6, iphone-64bit

I have updated my Xcode version from 5.3 to 6.0.1
 In simulator 'iPhone5s iOS 7 ' and 'iPhone5s iOS8', it is working fine. But when i want to build with simulator 'iPhone 6' and 'iPhone 6Plus', it is giving the following error.

![No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)][1]

I have used the libCorePlot static library also.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986256/1219956) solve your problem?