# Check dependencies... No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7s armv7)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have an existing iPhone project, and I have added WatchKit app to it. Upon compilation, I'm getting the "Check dependencies... No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7s armv7)." error.

This issue seems to be everywhere, and has been asked many times. For my case, I checked through everything I can and it seems that the issue is related to an static library which is linked to the iphone project.

Can anyone help?

Comment: does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986256/1219956) not help?

Comment: I resolved the problem by upgrading the iOS target version to 9.0 (previously set to 7.0) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Target-> build setting check under Architecture.

[image]

And check valid architectures all.

use this link to create architectural :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774768/xcode-6-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-when-building-for-ios-simul)