# ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking

I have an iOS app that was compiling fine until recently. It's under source control with git so there have been no changes to the code.

However, Xcode made some changes to the Project files which resulted in this error:

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

After following the instructions here [No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985909/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid)

and changing `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`, this error was fixed but now the project won't compile giving this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Obvious question first: where is the library file actually located and is that location in your project's library search paths?

Comment: @PhillipMills I have no idea where it is actually located. Where should I look? I can see Pods/AFNetworking and "Pods/Target Support Files". I assume it should be under one of those? Would it be a .a file and, if so, what would it be named?

Comment: I assume it would be called libAFNetworking.a but, since I don't do "Pods", I won't guarantee anything.

Comment: Interestingly this file does not exist. Neither does anything like *AFNetworking.a. So I assume it's not being built.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem: library not found for -lAFNetworking.
I've updated Pods: "pod install", and removed DerivedData: 
"rm -r  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

It does not help.

Problem was solved after upgrading cocoapods to 1.0.1 version:
"sudo gem install cocoapods"

I removed Pods folder and Podfile.lock and changed Podfile to new format
then "pod install" and removed DerivedData again